# Java Time Conversion to GMT / Formating

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, timezone

I'm Taking current time and want to convert it to GMT +00:00 / UTC .

```
Date dt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
out.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String current = dt.toString();
String result = out.format(dt);
```

`current = Tue Dec 24 17:35:59 GMT+04:00 2013`

and the result I get: 
     `result = Tue, Dec 24 2013 01:35:59 UTC`

Isn't it wrong ? I should have get `Tue, Dec 24 2013 13:35:59 UTC`   right ?

Comment: `hh` stands for 12 hr format && `HH` for 24hr format. Your output is correct in 12hr format. Use `HH` to get 13 instead of 1 as hour.

Comment: If you want a Date `Date dt = new Date();` is not only shorter, but faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capital 'H' in your SimpleDateFormat pattern to get the hour of the day in the format you want. Like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

The small 'h' stands for a hour of day in a PM/AM form (0 - 12)

Answer (score 1):

Use kk .
`DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", d.getTime());` this may be solve your problem

Comment: In this particular case HH is more logical. Your timeformat would allow 24:59 to be a time, I think.

Comment: This constant was deprecated in API level 18. Use a literal 'H' (for compatibility with SimpleDateFormat and Unicode) or 'k' (for compatibility with Android releases up to and including Jelly Bean MR-1) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The date format you should use is

```
"EEE, MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
```

instead of

```
"EEE, MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss z"
```

The case of the hour position changes it between 12hr and 24hr format.

Answer (score 0):

Joda-Time makes this work easier.

```
DateTime now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( now );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume only the external representation is of interest. The following worked for me without further ado. It is based on the java.util.Calendar object and on the java.util.Formatter.

It seems that a calendar object acts like a date object with a varying time zone instead of a default time zone, and is accepted by the formatter in place of a date.

The test code was:

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
cl.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("cl="+String.format(
             "%1$ta, %1$td %1$tb %1$tY %1$tT %1$tZ", cl));
cl.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("cl="+String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, 
             "%1$ta, %1$td %1$tb %1$tY %1$tT %1$tZ", cl));
```

The result was:

```
cl=Mi, 06 Feb 2019 13:51:41 MEZ
cl=Wed, 06 Feb 2019 12:51:41 GMT
```